# Do Monstrous Creatures still only have AP6 when using Scything Talons?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Scything Talons have AP6, but to me it seems odd that a creature the size of a Carnifex with talons nearly twice the size of a human would have trouble cutting its way through a Guardsman's flak vest. I know that in the current edition of the rules being a Monstrous Creature does not automatically allow you to ignore armor saves like you could in earlier editions (I think 5th and earlier), but is there something in the Tyranids codex that I missed, or is a Carnifex using its Scything Talons really just AP6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 7th edition, all Monstrous Creatures are AP2 (Hammer of Wrath excepted). MCs have the Smash rule, and Smash gives all attacks AP2. The only other exception would be if the creature had a BETTER AP weapon.

Comment: Ah, alright. I thought that Smash merely governed the double-strength Smash Attack, but it seems I was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Also worth noting that along with Hammer of Wrath attacks the Tyranid tail biomorphs explicitly state that use their own profile and do not benefit from the MCs smash rule or other bonuses such as Furious Charge etc.